# Spark RDD functions on CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to load the **csv** file through **SparkContext** and after loading i need to perform any **RDD operations** on required columns of **CSV file**.
I was able to read csv file and fetch the required columns from JavaRDD. Now i need to perform any RDD operations on these columns.

This is what i have tried so far..

```
JavaRDD<String> diskfile = sc.textFile("/Users/hadoop/Downloads/Data_1.csv");

  JavaRDD<Object> newRDD = diskfile.cache().map(lines -> Arrays.asList(new String[]{
          lines.split(",")[0], 
          lines.split(",")[1]
        }

          ));
 System.out.println(newRDD.collect());
```

`newRDD.collect()` prints 0th column and 1st column of csv data. Now i need to perform any RDD operations on `newRDD`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get started with Spark RDD transformations then you can go to the following links :

[RDD-Basic-Examples](https://github.com/ypriverol/spark-java8/wiki/2-RDD-Basic-Examples)

[RDD API Examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html)

Word Count Example in java using the `flatMap, mapToPair, reduceByKey` transformations :

```
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...");
JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  public Iterable<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
  public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
});
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...");
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i know about RDD operations. here my requirement is to apply rdd operations on two columns of csv data.

Comment: wt operation you are looking for ?

Comment: i need to return column2 value with respective to max value of column1.

Comment: wt u need to apply is `sortByKey`.  you can use rdd.sortByKey(), it will sort the rdd based on the key

Comment: but my input RDD is of type Object, as per my knowledge soryByKey is only aplicable for RDD<key,value>. sorry if iam wrong

Comment: yes, in the map function u have written, create a map or touple2, so that u cn use `sortByKey`. U need to update your map function which would return rdd of key,value pair

Comment: can you share your idea how to return RDD<key,value> from RDD<Object>?